# Attach KendoTouch event to Kendo UI dynamically created button

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-mobile

I am using Kendo Mobile for the development of an app in Telerik.

I have a list that is populated dynamically using information that I receive from JSON call to a service. The app will then show that info in a list. The list contains links to another view which will contain more information.

However, to do this, I need to attach a KendoTouch event to the button dynamically. This touch event would extract a data tag from the button and display the correct information in the next view.

However, I tried, but failed to attach a KendoTouch event to a dynamically created button.

This is the code that I am using:

```
<ul class="story-choices">
  # if (typeof order[window.currentStory].choices !== 'undefined') { #
  # for (var i = 0; i < order[window.currentStory].choices.length; i++) { #
  <li class="story-choice">
  #= order[window.currentStory].choices[i].text #
  </li>
# } #
# } #
</ul>
```

As you can see, I am using a Template to dynamically populate a div. This template will run through a list of JSON objects and create the list items.

In Javascript I tried:

```
$(".story-choice").kendoTouch({
  tap: function(e) {
    alert("tap!");
  }
});
```

But this will only attach items that are already present the moment the view is shown.

I also tried:

```
$("ul.story-choices").on("click", "li", function (event) {
    alert("done");
});
```

but that does not work at all, as I need to have the KendoTouch - tap event to fire events on tapping the phone.
So, I currently have no way to attach this tap event to the new list items.

Any idea how I can do this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try attaching the `kendoTouch` event in the [list's `dataBound`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/mobile/ui/listview#events-dataBound) event. Be careful that sometimes kendo widget's `dataBound` event run before the elements are created. Put a `debugger` to check it out. In case of the event being called before elements are rendered, a common workaround is to use `setTimeout({..}, 1)` inside it. Take a try and tell us.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Sadly, it did not seem to solve the issue... It also seems odd that for such problem, Kendo does not offer a standard solution? It must happen often that elements on the page are dynamically created...

Comment: Ok, what if you attach the touch event to the grid itself but using [`filter`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/mobile/ui/touch#configuration-filter) set to `.story-choice li` or something like it?

Comment: Thanks again :-) Using your comments, I found the solution :-) I have to set the data role and tap of the list item as follows:
<li data-role="touch" data-tap="onTap">
Then I can set the onTap function to do whatever I want, and I can get any data attributes from the originating element. This also works for dynamically generated list items! Thanks again!

Comment: Nice to hear !! Best of luck..